# UML class diagram for domain with movies

Tags: inheritance, uml, associations, relationship, class-diagram

I am currently creating class diagrams in UML for a movie test domain. I would like to know if I am doing it right. Well, I have two alternatives (the first version in the first picture, the second in the second - I think the first one is better). I'm wondering if I've established the so-called "relationship owner" correctly, that is, from which class to which direction the relationships go. I also don't know if I didn't get multiplicity wrong (one to one, one to many etc.).

So on my domain I would like to have movies of course, the actors starring in those movies and directors. I wonder if the class name "Character" is good in this case, because I mean all the characters that take part in a movie - it can be director, actor but also for example "Batman". Maybe I should make a distinction here between "Movie Character" and then "Human", "Monster", whatever. But I don't know how to do it elegantly, will I then inherit from the Character class? I'm also wondering if I shouldn't put classes like City or Country together in one class called Address - but I wanted the classes to take attributes like in this case, that one is Master and the other is detail - and the relationship set in the right direction. I use only relations such as Inheritance and Dependency, I do not know if I should change something in this case.

Version 1
[image: Version 1]

Version 2
[image: Version 2]

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or advice!

Comment: I noticed that I can't add images in any form other than a link, sorry about that.

Comment: You will be able to do that once you got just a little reputation. Note though that this place is not really meant to review models. It's for single concrete questions.

Comment: You are using dependencies rather than associations. Movie/Genre relation just looks odd. There are questions/answers here about multiplicity already.

Comment: @qwerty_so Thank you! I didn't know. Should I use associations then? Why does Movie/Genre class relation look weird? Because of the fact that Genre is an enum?

Comment: Yes, use associations except for the enum where the dependecy need to be reversed and without any multiplicities.

Comment: @qwerty_so Thanks. I was using dependencies because I read that if we combine A and B then A depends on B and uses some of the objects in B, which fits in this case - because associations has only access to some of B but B doesn't have access to an A. That's why I thought dependencies fit better in this case.

Comment: @qwerty_so Can I ask if the other classes and relationships look at least somewhat acceptable?

Comment: Bluntly: no. See my 2nd comment.

Comment: I don't think the relationship between Character and Actor is one of inheritance (in version 2), nor is the one between Person and Character (in version 1). It is plausible that Character could inherit from Person perhaps...inheritance is a "is a kind of" relationship. Is Person a kind of Character? or Character a kind of Actor?

Comment: @muszeo My idea was that the Character class would include the entire cast playing in the movie - this would include the actor, director, but also characters played by actors (e.g. Spider-Man, or some other "superhero"). For this reason, I decided that Person could be a kind of Character. Character can be separated into Person but also into Movie Character, where there will only be characters from movies. What do you think?

Comment: @muszeo Although you may be right and it can probably be considered association rather than inheritance. My point is simply that Character is the class of all the people, creatures, actors and directors playing in the movie, and Person is information about all those "real" people.

Comment: Sorry for delay in reply. I think the actors and the characters they play are two different constructs. Cast is probably the linking entity, the thing that represents the many-to-many relationship between the non-fictional persons (actors) and the fictional ones (characters). The word cast can be used as a verb — “to cast” meaning to cast one thing as another (we use it like that in OO programming too), so I suspect Cast is a class that sits between the Actors and the Characters. Actors are always People, but Characters don’t have to be, so Person probably is only a super type of Actor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In short

Use inheritance very carefully. Prefer [association over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) whenever your inheritance is not a permanent truth from the birth to the death of an object. ANd keep in mind that dependencies between classes do not make any promises about objects of those classes.

### Some more explanations

Some clarifications on the UML syntax:

- I understand that your plain thick lines ended with a small hollow triangle represent a specialization/generalization relationship (aka inheritance). If this is correct, the triangle should be larger to avoid visual confusion.  Moreover multiplicity makes no sense with inheritance and should be removed.
- I understand that with the dotted line you intend to represent an association with multiplicity. If this is correct:

  - the association should be plain lines, because dotted lines are for dependencies, and multiplicity would make no sense.
  - the meaning you give to the arrow head would be unclear.  Do you use them to document navigability? In case of doubt, remove them. If you want to document ownership of the association end, use the dot notation instead. (we cannot say if it’s right or wrong, since it’s a decision on how your model sees the associations)

In view of your comments and the third model linked therein,  there are some key UML semantics you need to keep in mind:

- Inheritance is an ultra-strong relationship which means "*is (always) a*".  In your example, you may say that an `Actor` is always a `Person`, and hence, everything you say about a `Person` is also true for an `Actor`.  By the way,  you should avoid repeating inherited properties or methods, since it could create some ambiguity.
- Inheritance is not a substitute for aggregation,  composition or association.  You can for example not say that a `CrewMember` (one person) is always a `Crew` (a group of persons). A `CrewMember` belongs to a `Crew` but there are things that the crew can do together that the individual member can't.
- Inheritance is not suitable if it's not always true.  A `Character` for example may often be a `Person`.  But not always;: you can have ghost characters, comic characters, robot characters, or animals.
- Association means that there is some structural relation between some instances of the associated classes.  For example,  that one ore several persons live in one city, seems a very relevant assocaition.
- Dependency means that a class is dependent on another, i.e. without the other class it would not work or something would be missing.  It's a statement about the classes and not the objects.  I.e.  If you meant to say that `Person` is dependent on `City` you just say that the class Person would not work without knowing about City (for example, because the operation `sendPostCardFrom(city: City)` needs an argument of that type)  but you do not say anything about persons X, Y and Z.  If you want that X, Y and Z are related to city a, b, and c, you need an association.

About the model content, I'll not decide for you and there is no single truth.  I therefore prefer to draw your attention at potential issues.  I raise them in form of a question, up-to you to adjust the model based on your own answer:

- Common issues between the both variants:

  - Are `Actor` and `Director` really `Persons` ?  In this case, what with the Persons that are Actors and Directors at the same time (g.g. Clint Eastwood) ?  Or are `Actor` and `Director` just roles that a `Persons` takes for a given `Movie` ?
  - Is a `Character` really related only to 1 `Movie`? What to do with Indiana Jones, where the same character appears in several movies?
  - In a similar way, I wonder if there's really a single `Person` who lives in a `City` or if this should not be a many-to-many association?
- Issues regarding the differences:  `

  - Is a `Person` in version 1 a `Character` (inheritance) ? Or is a `Character` a representation of a `Person` (association: represents) ?
  - Is a `Character` in version 2 really an `Actor` and by transitivity also a `Person` (inheritance)? Or is the `Character` only associated with an `Actor`  (association: plays) ?

It's up to you to decide,  but wherever I asked a question about association or inheritance,  you should better think twice before using inheritance (i.e. prefer association/composition over inheritance)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. First of all, thank you very much for the answer! About UML Syntax - yes, thick lines with hollow triangle at the end represent inheritance. Dotted lines represented dependency but I understand that I shouldn't use them - from what I've read dependency is a much weaker relationship than association (and as you say, there shouldn't be multiplicity there) - should I not use them because of that? I wanted to use navigation to show who owns the relationship, but actually nnotation with a dot sounds much more reasonable.

Comment: My classes have only properties and no operations because it's very early version of the diagram - you are perfectly right! About potential issues: Actors and Directors are simply roles that people play in (one) given movie., and you are right - Character should be related to several movies, thak you for that (the same with the Person and City an many-to-many association.

Comment: About the main differences: originally Character was supposed to be a representation of a Person - but in my model I wanted to get a minimum of three levels of inheritance from the Person class (I need this for later testing) so it can be very confusing - my second idea is based on splitting the Person class into Cast and Movie Crew - I will send this version in the link: https://i.imgur.com/IfrsWxe.png  (sorry that dependency was not changed to association, I did it before I noticed you wrote :( )

Comment: @tomaszkolodziejski I've edited my answer slightly to summarise the main issues,  and clarify the problems I see with some of your use of inheritance.  I also tried to clarify why dependency is not suitable for what you really want to express.